# Python - how to add string depending on length to new list

Tags: python, sorting

I am fairly new to python and I am attempting to write a function that takes a list of strings (e.g. ['my', 'name, 'is', 'John']) and return a new list with these same strings in order of length. I have borken it down into four steps.  So far I have managed to compute the maximum length of all words, create empty lists (buckets).

Where I am struggling is with Step 3 - my lack of ability is preventing me from writing something that will look at the length of the word and place it in the corresponding bucket, for example if the word length is 8 characters long.  I can "hardcode" it so it is limited to length of x characters, however my abilities have me stumped there.

```
def empty_buckets(n): 
    """Return a list with n empty lists. Assume n is a positive integer. """ 
    buckets = [] 
    for bucket in range(n): 
        buckets.append([]) 
    return buckets 

def bucket_sorted(words):
    """Return a new list with the same words, but by increasing length.
    Assume words is a non-empty list of non-empty strings.
    """

    # Step 1. Compute the maximum length L of all words.
    for i in words:
        if len(i) > 0:
             L = len(i)
    print(L)

    # Step 2. Create a list of L empty lists (buckets).
    buckets = empty_buckets(L)

    # Step 3. Put each word in the bucket corresponding to its length 
    # for example words like'a' go in buckets[0], words like 'as' go in buckets[1] etc. 


    # Step 4. Put all buckets together into a single list of words.
    newList = []
    for k in buckets:
        if len(k) > 0:
            newList = newList + k
    return newList
```

Comment: `sorted` can come in handy for these cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This answer assumes that you are using a bucket sort approach as an exercise.)

Now's a good time to start practicing *functional programming* approaches.

- Step 1: use the built-in `max` function, and `map` with function `len` to calculate the lengths.

  ```
  L = max(map(len, words))
  ```
- Step 2: use a *list comprehension* here.

  ```
  buckets = [[] for i in range(0, L)]
  ```
- Step 4: (**optional** – your current approach is fine) instead of concatenating buckets in a loop, use `itertools.chain` to chain them together.

  ```
  from itertools import chain
  ...
  newList = list(chain(*buckets))
  ```
- Step 3: For each string `s`, use `len(s) - 1` as the bucket index (since Python list indices start at 0, not 1):

  ```
  for word in words:
      buckets[len(word)-1].append(word)
  ```

Putting the above all together:

```
from itertools import chain

def bucket_sort(words):
    # step 1
    L = max(map(len, words))

    # step 2
    buckets = [[] for i in range(0, L)]

    # step 3
    for word in words:
        buckets[len(word)-1].append(word)

    # step 4
    return list(chain(*buckets))
```

Test:

```
>>> bucket_sort(["my", "name", "is", "Sherlock", "Holmes", "."])
['.', 'my', 'is', 'name', 'Holmes', 'Sherlock']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint:- create a loop to look at each word, and inside the loop assign the length of the word to a variable and then use the variable.

I think you will also have less trouble if you change the `buckets` to a dictionary instead of a list, for easy referencing.